# Laravel String To Lower

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to convert a string to lowercase in a views page (index.blade.php)

The following is what I would like to achieve.

```
<img src="images/teamnamesml.jpg logo">
```

This is my attempt

```
<img src="images/{{ Str::lower($matchup->visitorTeam) }}sml.jpg">
```

I get this error

```
FatalErrorException in ed1bb29e73e623d0f837c841ed066275 line 71:
Class 'Str' not found
```

Do I have to import the class `Illuminate\Support\Str` to a specific file?

Comment: `Str` should be in the global namespace. Did you try `\Str::lower()` with the leading slash?

Comment: Also, check here for a list of useful Helper Functions: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers (note: There isn't one for lowercase, but I think that's because `strtolower` exists already)

Comment: Tried `\Str::lower()` does not work

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Why not just use the PHP built-in [`strtolower`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php)?

```
<img src="images/{{ strtolower($matchup->visitorTeam) }}sml.jpg">
```

Or, if you need full UTF-8 support you can use [`mb_strtolower($string, 'UTF-8')`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtolower.php) which allows umlauts and other fun UTF-8 stuff. This is what Laravel's [`Str::lower()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Support/Str.php#L253) function does.

Comment: Yes I can do that. That slipped my mind but now that I have asked the question it would be nice to find a solution using Laravel's `Str::lower($value)`

Comment: @user2759965 Just curious what's wrong with `strtolower`? It's a native function, it's faster and it's naming is very clear.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with `strtolower`, I am using it right now. However, I did ask for a solution for Laravel `Str::lower()` so I don't know if it's appropriate to accept `strtolower` as the answer.

Comment: Str::lower() = mb_strtolower($value, 'UTF-8')

Answer (score 24):

Because in the comments you asked still, how it works in the Laravel way, so here an alternative solution next to `strtolower` and `mb_strtolower`, which also work fine.

You have to add the namsepace in front of the method, that PHP and Laravel can find the method.

So, if you want to use it in Blade, do the following:

```
<img src="images/{{ Illuminate\Support\Str::lower($matchup->visitorTeam) }}sml.jpg">
```

If you want to use it in a Controller or Model, you have to add the namespace, where `Str` is in on the top:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
```

After that, you can call it without the namespace prefix:

```
Str::lower($test);
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [`mb_strtolower`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtolower.php) to be able to convert any character that has 'alphabetic' property, such as `Č, Ć` etc.